# How to get list of PID's of the processes in the group

Tags: linux, unix, ps

How to get list of PID's of the processes in the group of the process which is current, using ps one line. I have tried:

```
ps -g $$
```

but `$$` is not group id but only `PID`
How do I get `PGID` of `$$'?

Answer (score 2):

Use ps to get the pgid of a process:

```
ps -o pgid $$
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `pgrep`?

```
pgrep -g0
```

gives you the list of PID's of the processes in the group of the process which is current. (See `man pgrep`)

Note that the command outputs nothing, if job control (`set -m`) is active in shell, because current process has a new process group then.